# Is it possible to unlock the final Paragon/Renegade options of a New Game Plus if the imported Shephard was not perfectly Paragon/Renegade?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In my first playthrough of ME3, I played mostly Paragon but with some minor Renegade choices along the way, so I ended up with a maxed reputation bar with approximately a 90%-10% Paragon/Renegade split. This means I was unable to unlock the final Paragon (or Renegade) dialogue option near the end which is required to

> convince the Illusive Man to shoot himself.

[Apparently](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Endings), unlocking that dialogue option requires a 100% Paragon (or Renegade) score.

I've just started a New Game Plus, and since the Paragon/Renegade ratio appears to carry over, does my previous Renegade choices mean I'm already doomed to fail to unlock that option even if I only make Paragon choices this time around? Or do my choices in this playthrough overwrite the ones I made in the last one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of either paragon or renegade reputation. The ratio may change, but getting one does not decrease the other (though it may seem that way with a full reputation bar).

That said, I find your claim that one must have 100% x and 0% y reputation to succeed at the last check highly debatable. The reason the introduced reputation was to stop penalizing players for making decisions against their "alignment".

Comment: I might be wrong about the exact requirements for unlocking the final option, but as far as I can tell, my reputation bar was maxed several missions before the end. Although I did miss delivering an item (the dog tags) due to the Cerberus attack on the Citadel, so it's possible that that might be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

To access the final Charm/Intimidate on TIM, you have to have tried to influence him in each of your 6 previous conversations with him in the game. Whether those previous attempts were Paragon/Renegade does not matter, as long as it was a red/blue choice.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio to each other is irrelevant, it's the actual numbered amount of gained Par/Ren + rep that matters. You can in fact complete a second playthrough with 100% of the Para/Ren points necessary in both bars.

Comment: Do you know what number do you need?